# sed command to find a pattern and replace with quotes

Tags: unix, sed

How to fina pattern as below as replace using sed command

Find (examples)

```
"Students": 98,
"Students": 17,
"Students": 200,
"Students": 21,
```

Replace

```
"Students": "98",
"Students": "17",
"Students": "200",
"Students": "21",
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use sed? Did you try something?

Comment: Any other unix command should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put quotes around all numbers, you can use

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/"\1"/g'
```

If you want to only do it after `"Students":`, you can use

```
sed -E 's/("Students": )([0-9]+)/\1"\2"/g'
```

`-E` means that an extended regular expression follows.

`s/` means a substitution is being made, with `/` as the delimiter.

`\1` matches the first parenthesized part of the regex, and `/2` matches the second parenthesized part, etc.

`-g` applies the substitution to every match found

Comment: If it answers your question, go ahead and accept it!